# Knife Project says it projects, but it doesn't

Tags: knife-tool

I line up a shape to knife project, and I click the object being cut first.  Then I enter edit mode and click the cutting object.  Then I go to mesh and knife project.  It says it completed it but it doesn't actually do it.  Can anyone give me an explanation or a solution to this problem please?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yV5Kl4o13VE&t=551s  (Video Tutorial I'm following to try and make a helmet.)

[image: Picture of the object with the "cutter" object in front of it. No lines from the cutter object are visible on the main object.]

[image: The outcome I'm hoping to get with the lines going onto the object.]

Comment: might be several reasons. So that we don't have to guess, i would recommend providing your blend file so we can check it out. thx.

Comment: @RobinBetts, right, if multiple cutting objects Ctrl key. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: How do I provide my file within the question?

Comment: I've also done the method to knife project the object, but it still doesn't work.  It will say it has done the task but hasn't actually did it.

Comment: @apoc, you can upload your file using https://blend-exchange.com/ and paste the obtained link in your question or comments.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=Qmp14Nkv" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/Qmp14Nkv/)

Comment: Here you go, I think this should work?

Answer (score 4):

Once you are in Edit Mode for the object(s) you want to cut, additionally select the cutting object(s) in the Outliner, using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. Then use the knife project.

If some parts fail to be cut, that could be due to doubled vertices. Merge by distance to remove them.[image]

Comment: Thanks so much!  Now I can continue my progress